# Django query not working

Tags: python, django, view, models

Here's the thing. I have a model called User and an attribute counter that counts the number of page access. So, if a user already exists, I have to query up the db and for that user only to increase in counter. Otherwise, create a new user. I have an annoying error in the get method. How can I surpass it?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            u = form.save()
            try:
                obj = User.objects.get(user=u.user)
                obj.counter += 1
                obj.ipaddress = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
                obj.save()
            except Statistic.DoesNotExist:
                ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
                obj = User(user=u.user, counter=1, ipaddress=ip)
                obj.save()
            return {'status': 'OK'}
        else:
            return {'errors': form.errors}
    return {'status': 'NOT OK. GET method'}
```

Here's the error

```
get() returned more than one User -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were
```

Comment: what is your annoying error?, shouldn't you be `except User.DoesNotExist`?

Answer (score 3):

Django has amazing documentation on their QuerySet API. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

`get` only returns exactly 1 queryset.  If no queryset is found, or more then 1 queryset is returned, an error is raised.
To catch this particular error you have to specify `except User.MultipleObjectsReturned`,

Answer (score 0):

This means there are multiple users matching the query in your database. `get` should be used to fetch only one. It seems you are already coding for this but I think you are catching the wrong exception type. Try changing

```
except Statistic.DoesNotExist:
```

To

```
from django.core.exceptions import DoesNotExist
except DoesNotExist:
```

Comment: I find it improves readability. Just a personal preference mind.

Comment: I believe it will also **not** catch exceptions raised by a `get` of another class in the same `try` block so you can differentiate between an error you are expecting and one you aren't.

Comment: Yes it does. Allows fine-grained control.